# Using the l'hopital's rule for a $1^∞$ case

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I need to find the limit of:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1-2x)^{1/x}$$

I can see that this is a $1^∞$ case, so I will let $y =$ the equation and use the natural log on both sides:

$$\ln y = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln(1-2x) $$

Now it is a $∞\times0$ case, so I can do:

$$\ln y = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{\ln(1-2x)}}$$

and now it is a $\frac{∞}{∞}$ case. I think my mistake happens while I use the l'hopital's rule:

$$\ln y = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-x^{-2}}{-[\ln(1-2x)]^{-2}\times\frac{1}{1-2x}\times-2x}$$

$$\ln y = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-[\ln(1-2x)]^2}{\frac{2x^3}{1-2x}}$$

It is now a 0/0 case, and I have tried using the l'hopital's rule a few more times but to no such luck. Where did I make a mistake, and is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Use L'Hopital on $\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\ln (1-2x)}{x}$ instead. It is of $\frac00$ form.

Comment: @player3236 is the 0/0 form preferred over the ∞/∞ form?

Comment: No. It's just that it's simpler to differentiate in this case. You can even evaluate this limit without L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$ \frac{1}{x}\ln(1-2x)= \frac{\ln(1-2x)}{x},$$

which is the indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$ in the limit as $x \rightarrow 0.$ This is what you should apply L'Hopital's rule to. Why? Because differentiation will make the expression simpler -- it will get rid of the logarithm. You never want to apply L'Hopital's rule if you have to differentiate $1/\ln(f(x))$, as differentiation will not get rid of the logarithm in such a case -- it won't make the expression simpler. Any time you end up with a more complicated expression after L'Hopital's rule, you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate the limit, set $-2x=1/n,$ so that we now have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-2n}=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\right]^2,$$ given that $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous, so that the limiting value is $1/e^2.$